# Assembly: Reversing an array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I found a piece of code here in a thread called "Reversing an array in assembly" and tried to apply it to my assignment. Here is the error codes I'm getting and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it from here...

```
1>FirstAssignment.asm(29): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
1>FirstAssignment.asm(34): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
1>FirstAssignment.asm(36): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
1>FirstAssignment.asm(38): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
```

Code:

```
    ; Assignment 1
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
; .386
;.model flat, stdcall
; .stack 4096
; ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword
.data
Uarray WORD 1000h, 2000h, 3000h, 4000h
Sarray Sword - 1, -2, -3, -4

.code
main proc
movzx eax, [Uarray]
movzx ebx, [Uarray + 2]  //all these are part of part 1 of homework
movzx ecx, [Uarray + 4]
movzx edx, [Uarray + 6]
movsx eax, [Sarray]
movsx ebx, [Sarray + 2]
movsx ecx, [Sarray + 4]
movsx edx, [Sarray + 6]

mov ax, LENGTHOF Uarray/2; Moves the length(divided by 2) into the eax register.
mov bx, 0; Sets the ebx register to 0 to serve as the counter.
mov cx, LENGTHOF UARRAY; Loads the length of the array into the ecx register.
mov dx, [Uarray + 6]; Sets a counter that starts at the end of the array.


L1:

mov ax, UArray[si + (TYPE Uarray * bx)]; Assigns to eax the value in the current beginning counter.

xchg ax, Uarray[si + (TYPE Uarray * dx)]; Swaps the value in eax with the value at the end counter.

mov Uarray[si + (TYPE Uarray * bx)], ax; Assigns the current beginning counter the value in eax.

dec dx; Decrements the end counter by 1.
inc bx; Increments the beginning counter by 1.
loop L1



call DumpRegs
; invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

This is my first attempt at writing an assembly language programs so please go easy on me and dumb everything down as much as possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Since your array is made of words, you should use word registers or `movsx`/`movzx` as you did in the first part (where you apparently haven't learned anything ...)

Comment: Do I need a `movsx/ movzx` for the xchg? And if I do, where would I put it in that statement? And I'm supposed to write it "thinking" that the user might change the size of the array and type

Comment: If you want to keep the `xchg` you need to use word sized register i.e. `ax` instead of `eax`. You can't write asm code without knowing the array type (due to endianness you need to know the item size)

Comment: `movzx ax, UArray[esi + (TYPE Uarray * bx)]; Assigns to eax the value in the current beginning counter.

xchg ax, Uarray[esi + (TYPE Uarray * dx)]; Swaps the value in eax with the value at the end counter.` I changed the registers, but am getting invalid use of registers on these two lines

Comment: You must keep using 32 bit registers for addressing, that is `ebx` and `edx` in those two lines. Also the first one should be a simple `mov` since you are now loading a 16 bit word into a word register (nothing to extend there).

Comment: I updated my code in my original post to what I have now. Still getting errors on `1>FirstAssignment.asm(34): error A2032: invalid use of register
1>FirstAssignment.asm(36): error A2032: invalid use of register
1>FirstAssignment.asm(38): error A2032: invalid use of register`

Comment: I'm not using ebx or edx anymore, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: As I said, you must keep using 32 bit registers in the addresses.

Comment: is there any chance you could write up a short example? I'm a very visual person when it comes to assembly; mainly because it confuses the hell out of me

Answer (score 0):

```
mov ebx, 0                   ; beginning counter
mov ecx, LENGTHOF UARRAY - 1 ; end counter

L1:

mov ax, UArray[esi + (TYPE Uarray * ebx)]; Assigns to ax the value in the current beginning counter.

xchg ax, Uarray[esi + (TYPE Uarray * ecx)]; Swaps the value in ax with the value at the end counter.

mov Uarray[esi + (TYPE Uarray * ebx)], ax; Assigns the current beginning counter the value in eax.

inc ebx      ; Increments the beginning counter by 1.
dec ecx      ; Decrements the end counter by 1
cmp ecx, ebx ; compare end to beginning
ja L1        ; continue if end > beginning
```